# Heating a 10W, 22-ohm ceramic resistor on a standard perfboard

Tags: resistors, heat, ceramic, insulator

I have a small project that consists of controlling the temperature of a 10 W, 22-ohm ceramic resistor. The circuit is assembled on a regular perfboard; I could just make use of both legs and keep the resistor at some height. But I would like to assemble the resistor so that it is fixed in the perfboard.

The temperature will vary between room temperature (no heating) and 75ºC.

My question is: in order to keep both perfboard and resistor in a good condition, can I solder the resistor completely flat on the perfboard?

I think 75ºC might damage the touching surfaces of the perfboard and the resistor, or the lack of airflow under the resistor might overheat it and make the control process a bit harder, so the resistor might need to be fixed at some height with the help of other components. In that case, can anyone suggest a reliable method that will both protect the perfboard from melting/burn marks and ensure a fixed position for the resistor?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As the question is a bit unclear, let me try to rephrase it: is there any material/component I can place between the ceramic resistor and the perfboard that will both hold the resistor in place and protect the perfboard from melting or charring? I thought of an IC socket (which actually prevents the resistor from moving to the sides) with a layer of some insulator on top... is it a good solution?

Comment: A lot depends on the material the perfboard is made of. There is hardware to do what you want but I push the lead through, back up and then down again and solder it so it will stay rigidly in place.  If external force is applied the leads will bend.  I do not think it is needed but you can place some aluminized tape on the perfboard to shield the resistor from the board. This will reflect some of the radiated heat.

Comment: @Gil Thank you very much for your feedback and suggestions. The lead bending when an external force is applied is exactly my problem, as I am trying to assemble a board that can be shared among students and must be sturdy for that purpose.

Comment: sounds like this could be a good application for PTC resistors. This devices are self regulating.

Comment: @arnisz Hi there, the purpose of this project is to control the power delivered to the resistor by measuring its temperature with an RTD and implementing a control loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

75 C ought not to damage perfboard even if it is a cheap and shoddy material. Had you said 95 C, I'd recommend placing an electrically and thermally insulating material underneath the resistor. A few layers of Kapton tape stuck to the perfboard would suffice, or if you want something that looks a bit nicer you could mill a resistor-width groove in a piece of PTFE, sandwiching it between resistor and board.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Normally power rating max results in a 100’C rise , so for your heater design use 50% of the max rated power for free open convection air cooling raised say >= 2cm above open space board then derate power needed if you add insulation according to added Rth thermal resistance insulation (‘C/W)to achieve same temp.

Consider thermal resistance of sensor to heat emitter and target device so that temp gradients are limited by thermal insulation away from other parts. So dual sensors or proper oven design may require small forced air circulation velocity to lower thermal resistance between heater and target, or by heatsink thermal resistance.

A diagram is essential to advise further.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQKM11.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and complete answer. However, my question might have sounded a bit different from what I was trying to ask, as I am not a native speaker. Nevertheless, I was actually asking for advice on *how* to mount the resistor (e.g. mechanically speaking, any specific materials) so that it is fixed (not just soldered by its legs at some height, hence free to move if touched).

Comment: Again, thank you for adding your diagram. I edited my question a few hours ago so that what I am asking for (specifically) was made clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using standoff terminals, like these from Keystone Electronics on Digi-Key.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, I am not finding a way to ensure the resistor leads won't break with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Solved

[image]

https://www.ebay.com/itm/183592768700?hash=item2abefb54bc:g:mA8AAOSwdW9aCk-K

If they break one of these the board is gonna break too

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That structure looks sturdy, of course, but the question about whether or not the heat will damage the perfboard still holds.

Comment: 75C isn't that hot.   PCB's are routinely passed through mass soldering machines (reflow oven) that is so hot it melts all the solder at one time.

Comment: I would suggest try it...see if your board gets crispy.  They don't catch fire or fail rapidly...instead an overheating resistor will slowly char the board.  You'll be able to see it.   Cook one at about 50% more power for a couple weeks and check the board after.   USE FR4 RATED PCB MATERIAL

Comment: Thank you for your input; as a matter of fact, if the perfboard can withstand the temperature conditions I mentioned, this structure might not even be needed. I was worried about soldering the leads leaving some height: this would leave the resistor free to move, which could end up destroying the resistor or the copper on the perfboard.

Comment: Given a question without measureable specs, I fail to understand the ignorance of those who down-vote.  Try to define your question in measurable terms with all unknowns stated.  Thermal resistance, power input , temperature rise and thermal isolation. It's a simple Ohm's Law question for thermal resistance doh!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I also did not understand the downvotes, and I did not upvote your answer at the time because I was new at the forum (already did, as your theoretical explanation was very interesting to me). However, what I was looking for was just something to place between the resistor and the board. Still thankful for your input!

Comment: It’s some arm-chair critic who has no values or experience to share (-1) except discontent